# Do rogues get sneak attack and trapfinding automatically?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation

When I start as a level one halfling rogue, do I get sneak attack 1d6 and trapfinding naturally (as in that's not something I need to get in feats or skills) or does that just mean that's something it does better if I wanted to use skill points/feat on that?
(Question was formed while looking at table 3-15: The Rogue.)

Also, how do I find out how much experience I need to level?

Comment: Do you own a Player's Handbook?

Comment: This may sound a bit harsh, but you need to stop looking at the tables and *read the rules*. That's about 100 pages of rules and you need to read them. We will not be able to provide a shortcut. There is not shortcut. You will need to read them yourself.

Comment: Welcome to the site! It appears you're new to the hobby, so thank you for taking an interest. Much of the stuff online will be incomplete, so if you don't have an actual, physical *Player's Handbook* yet, this will be frustrating. Don't despair at the downvotes. Good questions and answers can easily make up for initial missteps. Good luck and keep participating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Page 23 of your Player's Handbook** (I am assuming you have one) states:

> **Class Table:** This table details how a character improves as he or she gains levels in the class. Some of this material is repeated from Table 3–1: Base Save and Base Attack Bonuses, but with more detail on how the numbers apply to that class.

---

**Page 49 of your Player's Handbook** (I am assuming you have one) contains Table 3–15: The Rogue.

When you look at the "Special" column of the [Rogue](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/rogue.htm) class table, that is what you get upon taking that appropriate level in that class.

Upon 1<sup>st</sup> level, which you start off as, you automatically get

> [Sneak Attack](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/rogue.htm#sneakAttack) +1d6, [Trapfinding](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/rogue.htm#trapfinding)

---

**Page 22 of your Player's Handbook** (I am assuming you have one) contains Table 3–2: Experience and Level-Dependent Benefits. It is **not** "Open Gaming Content" which is why you will not find it on websites such as www.d20srd.org.

Please read your Player's Handbook a little more thoroughly. Or, I suggest playing [Dungeons & Dragons Online](https://www.ddo.com/en). or [Neverwinter](http://www.arcgames.com/en/games/neverwinter). They don't require Player's Handbooks.

---

This is what a Player's Handbook looks like:

[image: Player's Handbook 3.5 Edition]

Answer (score 6):

### A character automatically gets what the table says the character gets...

Really. It just happens. The benefit of taking the class level is getting the special stuff that goes with it.

#### ...But the [SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/index.htm) doesn't contain rules for creating or advancing characters

That's a deliberate choice on the part of Wizards of the Coast so the company can make money selling the [*Player's Handbook*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0786962461). You should get one.

Comment: have one...thats where the the question came from